# Lag when scrolling RecyclerView with A-Z filtering library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a problem when scrolling my `recycler view`. It's always lag, neither scrolling up or down. When I see the logcat, this is the message

I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I don't know what's the problem, I really confused. Also, I combining fast scroller library from https://github.com/viethoa/recyclerview-alphabet-fast-scroller-android. It's work really smooth, except for the lag.

**Here is the mainactivity code :**

```
    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private View view_menu, view_click, view_list;
private ImageView btn_arrow_back;

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerViewFastScroller fastScroller;

private List<String> mDataArray;
private List<AlphabetItem> mAlphabetItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    fastScroller = (RecyclerViewFastScroller) findViewById(R.id.fast_scroller);

    mAlphabetItems = new ArrayList<AlphabetItem>();
    mDataArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    mDataArray = DataHelper.getAlphabetData();

    view_menu = (View) findViewById(R.id.menu_layout);
    view_list = (View) findViewById(R.id.list_vendor2);
    view_click = (View) view_menu.findViewById(R.id.click_vendor);
    btn_arrow_back = (ImageView) view_list.findViewById(R.id.arrow_back);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    List<String> strAlphabets = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mDataArray.size(); i++) {
        String name = mDataArray.get(i);
        if (name == null || name.trim().isEmpty())
            continue;

        String word = name.substring(0, 1);
        if (!strAlphabets.contains(word)) {
            strAlphabets.add(word);
            mAlphabetItems.add(new AlphabetItem(i, word, false));
        }
    }

    Log.d("isi_data"," "+mDataArray);

    ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mRecyclerView,false);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(mDataArray));

    fastScroller.setRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
    fastScroller.setUpAlphabet(mAlphabetItems);

    view_click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view_menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view_list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    btn_arrow_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view_list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view_menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

**Here is the adapter code:**

```
    public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>
    implements RecyclerViewFastScroller.BubbleTextGetter {

private List<String> mDataArray;

public RecyclerAdapter() {
    mDataArray = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public RecyclerAdapter(List<String> dataset) {
    mDataArray = dataset;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mDataArray == null)
        return 0;
    return mDataArray.size();
}

@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_layout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d("isi_data"," "+mDataArray.get(position));
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataArray.get(position));
}

@Override
public String getTextToShowInBubble(int pos) {
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= mDataArray.size())
        return null;

    String name = mDataArray.get(pos);
    if (name == null || name.length() < 1)
        return null;

    return mDataArray.get(pos).substring(0, 1);
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_alphabet);
    }
}
```

}

If you want the XML code, just comment. It's too long if I insert it here. The `data helper` class only to add the array list and send back to the `inactivity` class. Thanks

Comment: Do Yo know how to use profiling in Android Studio?

Comment: Nope, i don't know. I still new at android studio

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

if possible, make all elements of the RecyclerView with the same height. And add:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Use the default RecyclerView drawing cache methods and tweak them according to your case. You don't need third party library to do so:

```
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
```

Comment: I'll try your solution

Comment: Where should I put your code? Is it before i set the layout manager for my recycler view?

Comment: U just copy other answer bro. And I have tried it, but it not work

Comment: I will not write code I added as I have done in my project also

Comment: So, do u have any other solution? It still not work for me